# EPPlus - Excel as Mail attachment - Column Names are missing

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using `EPPlus`. My requirement is to send `excel file` as an `attachment`. So I populate the `DataTable` by defining the Columns & then adding rows.

Everything is working fine. Till the Attachment reaches the Email. But when the Excel file is opened then the `Columns which i have defined are missing`. The rows are appearing correctly.

```
.....
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
ms = DataTableToExcelXlsx(dt, "Attendance");
ms.Position = 0;
Attachment file = new Attachment(ms, "Attendance.xlsx");
message.Attachments.Add(file);
.....
smtp.Send(message);
```

...

```
public static MemoryStream DataTableToExcelXlsx(DataTable table, string sheetName)
        {
            MemoryStream Result = new MemoryStream();
            ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage();
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);

            int col = 1;
            int row = 1;
            foreach (DataRow rw in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn cl in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (rw[cl.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value)
                        ws.Cells[row, col].Value = rw[cl.ColumnName].ToString();
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
                col = 1;
            }

            pack.SaveAs(Result);
            return Result;
        }
```

Why columns are not appearing in the Excel. They are present in the Datatable. What is solution for this issue?

Comment: Is all the text in one column? I tried the above code and got an empty file. I changed how you return the memory stream to return new MemoryStream(pack.GetAsByteArray());

Comment: Where are you actually setting the "columns" (I assume you mean headers)?  I see if your nested `foreach` loops where you set the "rows", i.e. cell values based on row,col coordinate but do not see where you set, say, Row 1 cells of the worksheet to the header names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't add the Columns thats why they were not appearing :-

```
// Columns
            int rowIndex = 1;
            int colIndex = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns) //Creating Headings
            {
                var cell = ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];

                //Setting the background color of header cells to Gray
                var fill = cell.Style.Fill;
                fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);

                //Setting Top/left,right/bottom borders.
                var border = cell.Style.Border;
                border.Bottom.Style = border.Top.Style = border.Left.Style = border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

                //Setting Value in cell
                cell.Value = dc.ColumnName;

                colIndex++;
            }

            // Rows
            int col = 1;
            int row = 2;
            foreach (DataRow rw in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn cl in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (rw[cl.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value)
                        ws.Cells[row, col].Value = rw[cl.ColumnName].ToString();
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
                col = 1;
            }

            pack.SaveAs(Result);
            return Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

[XlsIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/XlsIO) is a .NET library that reads and writes Excel 2003/2007/2010/2013/2016 files. Using [XlsIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/XlsIO), you can import data table xls/xlsx document very easily. The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

**Step 1:** Create a console application

**Step 2:** Add reference to Syncfusion.XlsIO.Base and Syncfusion.Compression.Base; You can add these reference to your project using NuGet also.

**Step 3:** Copy & paste the following code snippet.

The following code snippet illustrates how to fill new rows from the last row using XlsIO

```
using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
{
    //Instantiate the excel application object.
    IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

    application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

    //Create a workbook with single worksheet
    IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);

    IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

    //Style definition 
    IStyle style = workbook.Styles.Add("Border");
    style.Borders.Color = ExcelKnownColors.Black;
    style.Borders[ExcelBordersIndex.EdgeBottom].LineStyle = ExcelLineStyle.Thin;
    style.Borders[ExcelBordersIndex.EdgeLeft].LineStyle = ExcelLineStyle.Thin;
    style.Borders[ExcelBordersIndex.EdgeRight].LineStyle = ExcelLineStyle.Thin;
    style.Borders[ExcelBordersIndex.EdgeTop].LineStyle = ExcelLineStyle.Thin;

    //Import data table
    worksheet.ImportDataTable(GetDataTable(), true, 1, 1);

    //Assgin created border
    worksheet.UsedRange.CellStyle = style;
    //Autofit columns
    worksheet.UsedRange.AutofitColumns();
    //Save the excel document
    using (MemoryStream excelStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(excelStream);
        workbook.Close();

        excelStream.Position = 0;
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment oAttachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(excelStream, "DataTableImported.xlsx");
    }
}
```

For further information about XlsIO, please refer our [help documentation](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/overview)

Note: I work for Syncfusion